# iFrame - how to load a page the user just came from?

Tags: iframe

I have an iFrame on a webpage and on all the other pages I have a button saying "discuss".  When the user clicks on this button it takes them to the iframe page.

I would like to know how to get the iframe to show the page the user just came from?  i.e the page with the discuss button on it.

This is so that eventually users will be able to discuss the page by viewing it in an iframe.

Thanks in advance,
Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example. Both files must be in the same directory.

`mainpage.html`:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      function gotoFramePageNormal() {
        window.open('framepage.html', '_top');
      }
      function gotoFramePageWithVar() {
        window.open('framepage.html?ref='+document.location.href, '_top');
      }
    </script>
    <input type=button value="Discuss" onclick="gotoFramePageNormal()" /> (normal referrer; via HTTP header)<br />
    <br />
    <input type=button value="Discuss" onclick="gotoFramePageWithVar()" /> (with URL variable referrer)<br />
  </body>
</html>
```

`framepage.html`:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      Source: <span id="srcurl">...</span>
    </div>
    <iframe id="theframe" width=800 height=600></iframe>
    <script>
      (function() {
        if (document.referrer=='') { //no referrer
          //parse URL variables
          var a=document.location.search,b,c;
          while ( (a.length>0) && (a[0]=='?') ) a=a.substring(1,a.length);
          //split variables
          a=a.split('&');
          //check each variable
          for (b=0; b<a.length; b++) {
            //split name and value
            c=a[b].split('=');
            if (c[0].toLowerCase()=='ref') {
              //show source url
              srcurl.innerText=decodeURI(c[1]);
              //set iframe source
              theframe.location.href=decodeURI(c[1]);
              return;
            }
          }
          //show no source url
          srcurl.innerText='none';
        } else { //has referrer
          //show source url
          srcurl.innerText=document.referrer;
          //set iframe source
          theframe.location.href=document.referrer;
        }
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `mainpage.html` uses URL variable to pass the source page to the frame page. Generally, this is done automatically by the web browser, but it's not reliable enough since that feature can be disabled by the user. The `framepage.html` will use both method to detect the source page URL.

Comment: Hi,  I have used this code exactly but have had no luck.  http://www.biolonline.co.uk/discuss/mainpage.html <That is the mainpage.html and the next link is the framepage.html > http://www.biolonline.co.uk/discuss/framepage.html  Thansk for your help - If i can get this to work I would be so pleased!